# How many times did Doctor Strange "loop"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, doctor-strange

At the end of [Doctor Strange](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211837/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

> Doctor Strange flies into the dark dimension and starts a time loop.

We only see maybe a dozen or so iterations, but the implication is that it went on for much longer.  Do we have any information as to how many times they went through that?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63012

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### We don't know exactly, but it's more than a few times

*The Hollywood Reporter* [asked this question](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/doctor-strange-end-screenwriter-explains-twist-944334) of screenwriter Jon Spaihts, who responded:

> There is a deliberate ambiguity there. It's one of those places where you want not to over explain. But I think he *[things]* **dozens of times, if not hundreds of times in there**. I think he really gets a taste of eternal sacrifice and sticks to his guns.

And Empire Online [sat down with](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/doctor-strange-scott-derrickson/) director Scott Derrickson, who said that a deleted line would have revealed that they'd gone through the loop thousands of times:

> "We had a line," recounts Derrickson, "where Strange said, 'we've been through this a thousand times. Literally. I fancied the idea that they went through it thousands of times before Dormammu finally realised he wasn't going to get out of it."

Comment: Going through that battle a few thousand times would do a lot to explain his suddenly becoming strong enough to be sorcerer supreme compared to those who have been training for much longer.

Comment: @kaine Can we train in a time loop? I don't think so. We'll just forget...

Comment: @user931 if they forgot, it wouldn't have worked as the big bad wouldn't get annoyed.

Comment: @kaine Why would Dormammu forget? He was beyond time.

Comment: If they forgot, Strange's line about having been through it a thousand times wouldn't have made sense.

Comment: @kaine being instantly obliterated isn't particularly great training.

Comment: The line Derrickson mentions implies that Dr. Strange did not forget.  Being able to reverse time is useless unless something is changed... traditionally it is the person in control remembers (think Rezero or video games). Technically, this could work if Dormyboy remembers and goes insane from it. Here it looks like both remember as Strange behaves differently between iterations.