# Does Dr Strange remember the pain when dying?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, time-travel, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

This is sort of related to this question, [How does Doctor Strange remember previous loops?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153962/how-does-doctor-strange-remember-previous-loops), but it does not answer what I am trying to find out.

### Being that a lot of the ways that Dr Strange is killed by Dormammu looked rather painful, does Dr Strange remember that pain each time he is killed?

Comment: It seemed like it...

Answer (score 5):

Just re-watched this scene on Blu-Ray, and it's unclear whether or not he remembers the pain from each death, but it is implied that he will be by Dormammu in the following conversation:

> DORMAMMU - You cannot do this forever.
>
> DR. STRANGE - Actually, I can. This is how things are now; you and me, trapped in this moment, endlessly.
>
> DORMAMMU - Then you will spend an eternity **dying**.
>
> DR. STRANGE - Yes, but everyone on Earth...will live.
>
> DORMAMMU - But you will suffer.
>
> DR. STRANGE - Well...pain's an old friend.

Comment: This seems logical! :)

Comment: Thanks!, I appreciate that. :)

Comment: @KyloRen-Was just wondering, are there any updates I can make to my answer for you to be willing to accept?

Comment: You’re very welcome, and your quote makes it even better! :)